# Help with dual booting Windows 8.1 Professional and Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows

I recently installed a clean version of Windows 8.1 Professional on my Lenovo Y500 (with Samsung 256GB 840 Pro SSD).

I have Windows all set up and running normally.

I am trying to dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10, but the installation procedure don't allow me to either "Install alongside..." or shows my SSD partitions correctly when I chose the "Something Else" option.

I have created a 25GB partition of free space in the Windows disk manager, but on the installation screen on Ubuntu, it shows the whole drive as a free space.

I have tried installing with a burned .ISO disk and a bootable USB, the results are the same for both.

Windows Disk Management screen:

http://imageshack.us/a/img855/9504/59zu.jpg

The Ubuntu installation screen:

http://imageshack.us/a/img62/2712/9g6i.jpg

I've ran into this problem before when trying to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 Professional a month ago. But I gave up and never resolved the issue.

--EDIT--
I tried what Eero Aaltonen suggested, and this is my result:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Warning: /dev/sda contains
GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table. However, it does
not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should. Perhaps it
was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT
partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now
using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?
Yes/No? yes
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 840 (scsi) Disk /dev/sda: 256GB Sector size
(logical/physical): 512B/512B Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Btw, you should add a comment if you make some changes. Otherwise I won't get any notification that something has happened :P

Comment: 13.10 has reached its EOL http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/07/17/ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2014/ please upgrade to 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the Ubuntu installer is unable to detect / read the partition table used by windows.

Boot with LiveCD and check what

```
sudo parted /dev/sda print
```

gives you ([original post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-viewing-drive-partitions-with-fdisk-parted/)).

I have an MBR partition table, so for me it states "Partition Table: msdos".

UPDATE: Hmm, your problem seems very similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295441/problem-installing-ubuntu-13-alongside-windows8-cannot-see-partition-system).
According to "Lenovo Y500 User Guide", the default boot mode on your laptop is UEFI. However, check which boot mode you are using before applying any fixes.

Also linking [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) since it contains a great deal of info about dual booting.